# relation between monadic filter and fold

Tags: haskell, monads, fold

Many higher-order functions can be defined in term of the `fold` function. For example, here is the relation between `filter` and `foldl` in Haskell.

```
myFilter p [] = []
myFilter p l = foldl (\y x -> if (p x) then (x:y) else y) [] (reverse l)
```

Is there a similar relation between their monadic versions `filterM` and `foldM` ? How can I write `filterM` in term of `foldM` ?

I tried hard to find a monadic equivalent to `\y x -> if (p x) then (x:y) else y` to plug into `foldM` without success.

Comment: is `myFilter p [] = []` redundant?

Comment: @ДМИТРИЙ МАЛИКОВ -- Yes, definitely.

Comment: Note that `foldl` is the "wrong" fold here, and `foldr` is the "right" one. For example, `myFilter` is `_|_` for infinite lists while original `filter` is not (well, given that predicate holds for at least one element).

Comment: @MatveyAksenov yep, redundant `reverse` is actually a nice symptom that `foldl` is used wrong.

Comment: @Aksenov. To my knowledge, there is no `foldrM` in `Control.Monad`. You are welcome to provide your own implementation (without using `reverse`) as an answer, together with the code expressing `filterM` in term of `foldrM`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like in D.M.'s answer, only without the `reverse`. Let the types guide you:

```
import Control.Monad
{-
foldM   :: (Monad m) => (b -> a -> m b) -> b -> [a] -> m b
filterM :: (Monad m) => (a -> m Bool)        -> [a] -> m [a]
-}

filtM :: (Monad m) => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [a]
filtM p xs = foldM f id xs >>= (return . ($ [])) 
  where 
    f acc x = do t <- p x 
                 if t then return (acc.(x:)) else return acc
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that it has any sense (since it has that strange `reverse`), but at least it type checked well:

```hs
myFilterM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [a]
myFilterM p l = foldM f [] (reverse l)
 where
  f y x = do
    p1 <- p x
    return $ if p1 then (x:y) else y
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is a minor problem with the execution order in your code, not sure why. Here is a simple test. filterM (const [True,False]) [1,2] => [[1,2],[1],[2],[]]. myFilterM (const [True,False]) [1,2] => [[1,2],[2],[1],[]]

Comment: It is because of `reverse`.

Comment: Ah! Now I understand. Instead of reversing `l`, I must `liftM reverse` the result of `myfilterM` to get the standard execution order. Everything is clear now.